# How To add total in Matrix in RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I used matrix in RDLC , I need to add a total at the bottom of the report to total each column like Below image ..[image]

Comment: What aggregate expression did you try ?

Comment: @Hardik: when i right click on the Group  in the Matrix table and selected the subtotal the Subtotal field comes right of the matrix table . but i need to get which I shown above ..

Comment: @Hardik:    **=sum(Fields!NetPay.Value)**

Comment: If you have rows repeating in Matrix you will be prompted subtotal at bottom and if you have repeating Columns then you will get subtotal right of the table.

Comment: try adding a single row and put expression there.